Importing OverlayModule in Karma not working
Test file :
import { ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { By } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { AlertsComponent } from './alerts.component';
import { RouterTestingModule } from '@angular/router/testing';
import { HttpProvider, StorageProvider, ToastMessageProvider } from '@ln/radix-providers-ng12';
import { AlertServiceProvider } from 'src/shared/providers/alert-service-provider.service';
import { ActivatedRoute, Router } from '@angular/router';
import { NotificationModule, ToastNotification, ToastNotificationService } from 'ln-components-angular/notification';
import { AlertResultProvider } from 'src/shared/providers/AlertResult.provider';
import { SelectedItemService } from '../../../../../_shared-business/src/services/selected-item.service';
import { AlertSupportLinksService } from '../../../../../_shared-business/src/services/AlertSupportLinks.service';
import { PaginationServiceProvider } from '@ln/pagination-module-ng12';
import { BackGroundService } from 'src/shared/services/background.service';
import { HttpClientTestingModule } from '@angular/common/http/testing';
import { SharedModule } from 'src/shared/shared.module';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { IconsRegistry } from 'ln-components-angular/icon';
import { ModalService } from 'ln-components-angular/modal';
import { Overlay, OverlayModule } from '@angular/cdk/overlay';


describe('FrAlertsComponent', () => {
  let component: AlertsComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<AlertsComponent>;

  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [
        RouterTestingModule,
        HttpClientModule,
        OverlayModule
      ],
      declarations: [AlertsComponent],
      providers: [
        StorageProvider,
        AlertServiceProvider,
        { provide: HttpProvider, useClass: HttpProvider },
        { provide: ToastNotificationService, useClass: ToastNotificationService },
        AlertResultProvider,
        SelectedItemService,
        AlertSupportLinksService,
        IconsRegistry,
        PaginationServiceProvider,
        ModalService,
        BackGroundService,
      ]
    })
      .compileComponents();
  });

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AlertsComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should change active tab on click', () => {
    const tabElements = fixture.debugElement.queryAll(By.css('li'));

    // Assuming the first tab is active initially
    expect(tabElements[0].classes['active']).toBeTrue();

    // Click the second tab
    tabElements[1].triggerEventHandler('click', null);

    fixture.detectChanges();

    // The first tab should no longer be active, and the second tab should be active
    expect(tabElements[0].classes['active']).toBeFalse();
    expect(tabElements[1].classes['active']).toBeTrue();
  });
});

First I am trying to import my ToastNotificationService then I have an error that say

R3InjectorError(DynamicTestModule)[ToastNotificationService -> Overlay -> Overlay]:
NullInjectorError: No provider for Overlay!

Then I am trying to import the OverlayModule but I have the following error

inject() must be called from an injection context


"First I am trying to import my ToastNotificationService" Services cannot be imported via imports.

@guiz please share how you imported OverlayModule, importing it should work!

@NarenMurali I have updated the code with OverlayModule import

@guiz try importProvidersFrom(OverlayModule) inside the providers array instead!

after adding importProvidersFrom(OverlayModule) I have this error :  Invalid provider for the NgModule 'DynamicTestModule' - only instances of Provider and Type are allowed, got: [..., ..., ?[object Object]?]

okay nevermind it works when updating angular to version 15 however I got a new error : inject() must be called from an injection context. I have tried to mock with spy but it is the same thing

It occur when I am trying to import external dependencies. I have tried to mock but still not working

@guiz please share the details of AlertsComponent and ToastNotificationService

Since there is no details provided for further solving this issue.
This is one way to circumvent this problem and continue coding.
First we create a spyOn the class  using createSpyObj and serve this class using useClass inside this we do not use Overlay and then modify the spys to make the component code work with it.
toastNotificationServiceMock = jasmine.createSpyObj<LoginService>('ToastNotificationService', ['someMethod', 'someMethod1', 'someMethod2']);
...
describe('FrAlertsComponent', () => {
  let component: AlertsComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<AlertsComponent>;

  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [
        RouterTestingModule,
        HttpClientModule
      ],
      declarations: [AlertsComponent],
      providers: [
        StorageProvider,
        AlertServiceProvider,
        { provide: HttpProvider, useClass: HttpProvider },
        { provide: ToastNotificationService, useClass: toastNotificationServiceMock },
        AlertResultProvider,
        SelectedItemService,
        AlertSupportLinksService,
        IconsRegistry,
        PaginationServiceProvider,
        ModalService,
        BackGroundService,
      ]
    })
      .compileComponents();
  });

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AlertsComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should change active tab on click', () => {
    const tabElements = fixture.debugElement.queryAll(By.css('li'));

    // Assuming the first tab is active initially
    expect(tabElements[0].classes['active']).toBeTrue();

    // Click the second tab
    tabElements[1].triggerEventHandler('click', null);

    fixture.detectChanges();

    // The first tab should no longer be active, and the second tab should be active
    expect(tabElements[0].classes['active']).toBeFalse();
    expect(tabElements[1].classes['active']).toBeTrue();
  });
});


So as per the first error states that you have imported overlayModule and added in the imports array but didn't add in the providers array.

You need to inject your service like this inside beforeEach



toastNotificationService = TestBed.inject(ToastNotificationService);



Hope it works, happy coding!
